# How to schedule Posts to publish in rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple scaffold "Post", now I want to add scheduling to it so I can create a post and put date to it and Post will only get created(actually published) at that time.

I can see I need to use 'whenever' gem for cron and probably want to play with published_at field but I am little confused how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to just add a published_at field because you actually already have the record there.

```
# Add columns. (DB migration)
add_column :posts, :draft, :boolean, :default => true
add_column :posts, :published_at, :datetime

# Define scopes. (model)
#
# These set up shortcuts that will allow you to do:
#   Post.draft
# instead of this in many places:
#   Post.where(:draft => true)
# Or:
#   Post.published
# instead of:
#   Post.where(:draft => false).where('published_at <= ?', Time.zone.now)
scope :draft, where(:draft => true)
scope :published, proc {
  where(:draft => false).where('published_at <= ?', Time.zone.now)
}

# If the user does not set published_at but sets post to public, automatically
# set published_at to the current time before persisting the record to the
# DB. (model)
before_save :ensure_published_at, :unless => :draft?
protected
def ensure_published_at
  # Set it to current time if none has been specified.
  self.published_at ||= Time.zone.now
end

# Might be helpful if you have a "Publish" action. (model)
#
# This already sets draft to false and published at to the default (because of
# ensure_published_at above:
#   post.publish!
def publish!
  self.draft = false
  self.save!
end

# Finally, fetch the published posts: (controller action)
# It's best to also add pagination and ordering.
@posts = Post.published
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the code what is going on. It will help me a lot

Comment: I thought the comments made that clear enough. I added more comments, especially on usage.

Comment: Hi Kristin, just wondering, will you suggest me to use delayed_job gem instead of using cron and hitting the server every minute ? Thanks

Comment: If you use cron and run a Rake task (an instance of Rails) every few hours, it might cause spikes in memory usage. You will also have to manage situations like what if your Rake task now has not yet completed and cron is already scheduled to run another Rake task -- will your RAM be able to handle those.

With `delayed_job`, you consistently have a second Rails instance, and this works on the background jobs as soon as they come in. So you get faster response, assurance that you only get one additional Rails instance, management of delayed jobs (tasks are DB backed, can do retries), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can show you the code actually working in one of my projects as example:

```
# config/schedule.rb:
#  Once wheneverifyed - asks cron to call rake task `posts:publish` every minute.
#  See whenever docs at https://github.com/javan/whenever.
every 1.minute do
  rake 'posts:publish', environment: environment
end

# models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Every post has
  #  status - either PUBLISH_WAITING or PUBLISHED
  #  publish_at - date/time post need to be published
  #  published_at - actual time post was published (in this example it'll always be equal to publish_at)

  PUBLISH_WAITING, PUBLISHED = 'not_published', 'published'

  scope :publish_waiting, where(status: Post::PUBLISH_WAITING)
  scope :ready_for_publish, where('publish_at <= ?', Time.now)

  # Method to make post published!
  # Warn: it doesnt check if it is time to publish! Just do that.
  def publish_now!
    self.status = Post::PUBLISHED
    self.published_at = self.publish_at
    save!
  end
end

# lib/tasks/posts.rake
#  Define rake `posts:publish` task,
#  which when called searches through all not published
#  (but ready to be published) posts and publishes them.
#  You can call that task manually from CLI `$ rake posts:publish` to check.
namespace :posts do
  desc "Publish posts with cron on certain time"
  task :publish => :environment do
    Post.publish_waiting.ready_for_publish.find_each do |post|
      post.publish_now!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me the code little ? it will help me a lot if I understand what is going on

Comment: Please, see comments I added. Good luck!

Comment: @laise- Hi Laise, just wondering, will you suggest me to use delayed_job gem instead of using cron and hitting the server every minute ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, personally I think delayed_job (or may be other MQ solution) is a better solution than cron+raketaks and gives you more advantages.